# For-in loop does not properly work on a `Partial<Record<...>>`

Tags: typescript

The following code turns some keys into numbers:

```
export type Dict<K extends keyof any, T> = Partial<Record<K, T>>;

function numberized(obj: Dict<string, string>, keys: string[]): Dict<string, string | number> {
  const result: Dict<string, string | number> = {};
  for (const key in obj) {
    const value = obj[key];
    result[key] = keys.includes(key) ? parseFloat(value) : value;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The compiler complains with:

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
const value: string | undefined
```

However, from the construct

```
  for (const key in obj) {
    const value = obj[key];
```

the compiler should know that `value` can't be undefined.

Comment: That's not strictly true. The key can still be in the object and have a value of `undefined` and still be part of the `for in` loop and also be a valid `Partial` object

Comment: Do you have an example where it breaks?

Comment: if you pass `obj = { a: undefined }` when `key` is `a`  then `value` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Is it possible to define Dict in such a way that it doesn't allow that?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with the definition of `Dict` (although TS 4.4 has a new option [exactOptionalPropertyTypes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#exact-optional-property-types) that might help). The problem is more to do with `for in` and how the object you pass to it might be of a given TS type but also have additional properties TS didn't account for. It's probably wise that TS (and you) err on the side of caution when using that one

Comment: I think `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` is what I am looking for. Lemme try.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiBLAxjAPAaTlBmADsATAZzgGthEIAzOAQ1MQBo4AVAPjgC8cAAotYGFgBtcAJWBZo5Alz68A3ACgNjAK6kcGCKTikdAWwBGwKBgBewcgAoIFgFYAudNjyUYN0gDmXL7+AbxcdIiUniEYgQDaALoAlJ6YOLixgcF+cQFwAD4m5lZQ-ADeGnBwCqS+cFDAlDqSMGnembnZcFn5RaaW1vxC5QC+mtWM0HCOtfWRcHFwLq7JcJXV1XPwAG5SOqhCK-GRiRObjc2tJ-SJgrT0lAB0cViSOuRNjpFrAPxwYDElGAADFJBAWDBHHt3sA1p4YQdzqMqg1gDAdFBjJcWjBNKMgA still fails

Comment: I believe here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73708429/why-do-object-values-for-a-partial-record-have-undefined-typings