# Why do Object.values for a Partial Record have undefined typings?

Tags: typescript, partial

When extracting `Object.values` from a Partial Record, the values are a union between what I would expect and `undefined`.

```js
const example: Partial<Record<string, number>> = {}
const values = Object.values(example)

// strangely, the typing for values is as follows:
// const values: (number | undefined)[]
```

Instead of `(number | undefined)[]`, I would expect it to be `number[]`. Every value in practice is defined, and, unless I'm missing something, always will be.

Code Sandbox showing the issue (with react scaffolding) can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-sea-m1t4yt?file=/src/App.tsx)

This seems likely to be some artifact of the type system, but I'd like to understand what's happening, and if there's any way to avoid this behavior.

Comment: You made all properties optional with `Partial`, so `example = { a: undefined }` is valid which produces an `undefined` value.

Comment: A type like `{ foo?: number }` allows for a value like `{}` or `{ foo: 42 }` or `{ foo: undefined }`. That's just how optional properties work.

Comment: I've been using `Partial<Record<..` to generally type any sort of string -> object map, and I've been sort of thinking of like a Scala partial function, in that the range of the map is limited on the `string` type (not all strings result in an object in the map), as opposed to a Record that maps from an exhaustive Enum to some value. If I don't use partial, then indexing the record results in an object, but in reality it might be undefined. Is this a bad way of thinking about it?

Comment: `Partial<Record<string, number>>` is equivalent to `{[x: string]: number | undefined}`, just like `Partial<Record<"a" | "b", number>>` is equivalent to `{a?: number | undefined, b?: number | undefined}`.  You might hope you could disable this `undefined`-adding behavior with `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` but there's kind of a bug at [ms/TS#46969](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46969) where `Partial` always adds `undefined` to index signatures even with that enabled.  Would you like this written up as an answer? (If you reply, mention @jcalz or I won't be notified)

Comment: An optional property simply means that `obj.foo` might give you `undefined`. Whether because `foo` doesn't exist or it exists and it's `undefined`. That's how you can think of optional properties. `Partial<>` makes all properties optional.

Comment: @jcalz An answer would be helpful if you have time, but I get what you're saying, I've been thinking of `Partial<Record<...` incorrectly. I've been thinking of it as a logically partial map, so indexing it might result in undefined, but any value present is defined (not undefined). Is there a different way to achieve those semantics?

Comment: This blog describes the issue, but its solution is to use `Partial`: https://dev.to/sarioglu/avoiding-unintended-undefined-values-while-using-typescript-record-4igo

Comment: Just use `{[k: string]: number}` aka `Record<string, number>`.  You don't need `Partial<Record<string, number>>`; there's no such thing as an "optional index signature", and index signatures already don't expect every possible property to be there (indeed, `{[k: string]: number}` would be a fairly useless type if you had to add a property for *every possible key*).  You only need `Partial` for non-index signatures like `{a: number, b: number}`.  Anyway I'll write up an answer when I get to it

Comment: @jcalz but if `foo` is a `{[k: string]: number}`, and I access `foo["some-non-existant-key"]` it will be typed as `number`, not `number | undefined`. I'd like more type safety if possible-- see that blog I linked above, it goes more into the issue.

Comment: Then you want `—noUncheckedIndexedAccess`, but it will annoy you in other situations.

Comment: And if that’s important to you then you should put it in the question, otherwise it’s not obvious that it’s in scope.

Comment: @jcalz ooh, that's what I was looking for, thanks! And fair enough, this kind of derailed from my original question.

Comment: Okay I wrote up the whole crazy story of optional properties and index signatures and their sordid love/hate relationship with `undefined`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In everything that follows I will assume we are all using [the `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict), in particular [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#strictnullchecks-on).  If you don't have `--strictNullChecks` enabled then most of the following discussion involving the `undefined` type won't apply, but you probably wouldn't have the issue raised in this question in the first place.

---

[The `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) is implemented like `type Partial<T> = {[K in keyof T]?: T[K]}` and applies the  [optional mapped type modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to make all of the resulting properties optional.

[The `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) is a mapped type implemented like `type Record<K, V> = {[P in K]: V};` and when you do that with `string` as the key it results in a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) like `type Dictionary<V> = {[k: string]: V};` where any property whose key is of type `string` must have a value of type `V`.

---

I really wouldn't recommend mixing [optional mapped type modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) (`Partial<T>`) with [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) (`Record<string, V>`).  Both of them do, uh, *interesting* things with [the `undefined` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) by default, and there are compiler options to change this default behavior to produce other, uh, *interesting* behvior which some people prefer and other people do not.  And no matter what settings you use, the combination of both of these together is probably going to make you unhappy, at least as of TypeScript 4.8.

---

First, [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties): in `--strict` mode, TypeScript doesn't really distinguish *missing* properties from ones that are *present-but-`undefined`*.  It's often reasonable to treat those as the same thing, since reading either give you `undefined`.  But should you be allowed to *write* `undefined` to the value?  Or should you be able to read `undefined` after you've used [the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check for the presence of the property?  This depends on what you think "optional" means.  By default, TypeScript says yes, if a property is optional then you should be able to *write* `undefined` there.  And therefore `{x?: string}` and `{x?: string | undefined}` are identical types.

Don't like that?  Well, neither did a lot of people... [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195), "Distinguish missing and undefined", was open for a long time and received hundreds of upvotes.   And so with TypeScript 4.4 [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) was introduced.  If you enable that, you will no longer be able to write `undefined` to an optional property unless `undefined` is explicitly included in the property type.  Hooray!

But it's not part of the `--strict` suite of compiler options.  Maybe if this feature had been introduced [with `--strictNullChecks` in TypeScript 2.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) it would have been.  But a lot of real-world code currently  expects that optional properties accept `undefined`, and it would break if this were introduced.  And it could be annoying.  The simple copying of a property from one object to another of the same type, like `a.x = b.x`, suddenly isn't acceptable if the property is optional.  You need `if ("x" in b) {a.x = b.x} else {delete a.x}` now.  That's an extra hoop to jump through and if you don't really care the missing/undefined distinction then you're not going to be happy about it.

So that's optional properties.

---

Now for index signatures: in `--strict` mode, TypeScript doesn't really distinguish *missing* properties from ones that are *present*.  This really doesn't matter for writing, but for reading it's noticeable.  The compiler presumes that if you are reading from a key that matches the index signature, then you know a value is actually there.  It doesn't account for the possibility that there is no property value and that you will get `undefined`.  If you wanted to make safer reads you could manually add `| undefined` to the type yourself, turning `{[x: string]: number}` into `{[x: string]: number | undefined}`, but now you are trading the unsafe-read problem for an undesirable-write problem much like the one with optional properties.  By default, TypeScript says that if you read from an index signature you're going to get a defined value (dereference at your own risk).

Don't like that?  Well, neither did a lot of people... [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778), "Option to include undefined in index signatures", was open for a long time and received hundreds of upvotes.   And so with TypeScript 4.1 [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) was introduced.  If you enable that, you will now receive a possibly-`undefined` value when you read from an index signature but you can't write one there.  Hooray!

But it's not part of the `--strict` suite of compiler options.  Maybe if this feature had been introduced [with `--strictNullChecks` in TypeScript 2.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) it would have been.  But a lot of real-world code currently  expects that index signature properties are present, and it would break if this were introduced.   And it could be annoying.  The simple iteration through an array by index, like `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { sum += arr[i]*arr[i] }`, suddenly isn't acceptable.  You need `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { const v = arr[i]; if (v !== undefined) { sum += v * v } }` now.  That's an extra hoop to jump through and if you don't use index signatures with arbitrary keys then you're not going to be happy about it.

So that's index signatures.

---

And you are *combining them*.  Well, even with `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` and  `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` enabled, `Partial<Record<string, number>>` is going to explicitly include `undefined` and therefore let you write `undefined` to its property values:

```
// @exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true
// @noUncheckedIndexedAccess
type X = Partial<Record<string, number>>;
// type X = { [x: string]: number | undefined; }

const x: X = {};
x.hello = undefined; // no error!
```

This is... a bug, I guess? Or a design limitation?  It's filed at [microsoft/TypeScript#46969](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46969) "`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`: `Partial` of index signature adds `undefined`" and marked as "Needs Investigation" as of TypeScript 4.8.

So no matter what you're looking for, you probably don't want to use `Partial<{[k: string]: XXX}>` at all.

Instead, you should think about what behavior you want given the available options above and their tradeoffs.  If you are planning to only *iterate* over the properties of your object, then I'd say you should just use `Record<string, number>` (leave off `Partial`) and leave the default `--strict` options.  If you are planning to index into your object's properties with arbitrary keys, then you should decide between the default settings and adding `| undefined` manually (accepting that `undefined` values may show up when you do iterate) or enable `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` and cause every index signature in your code base to start getting really worried about `undefined`.  It's up to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.8.3#code/PTAEAEFMA8EMGMAuB5ADoglgewHawDYAKATlqpMYgJ4AqV5AzgFyiLECukAsAFAgQ4sAVRzwAFpHgBrSABMAkjlkw5AQXjxIDBr2rlQADVABeUIViUMBADwAlSVmKzrDNhhwBzADSgc7ALYARhQAfCEA3Lz8epCGJqAA3qAA2tAsrsTuHgC6LH5BFKAAPqDsSpAAZu5y4aAAvry88LiuoGlxpgl1kTzQAHQS+PhY8WXKVTg1oPxYZAwYkEA)

Comment: A crazy, sordid story indeed! Thank you so much, this is incredibly informative. I've been using `<Partial<Record<..`s to roughly emulate the behavior of `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` in multiple places in my code for weeks now. I've now enabled `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` in my project, and only have a few changes I need to make to support it. It definitely better matches the way I think about index access in general. Anyhow, thanks again for this great answer, when the question is eligible for a bounty I'm definitely retroactively awarding it to you.