# proper typing for object-based map

Tags: typescript, types

Given `exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true` we trying to use object as a map:

```
type User = {name: string}

const userMap: {[key in string]?: User} = {}

userMap.a = {name: 'Elise'}
userMap.b = {name: 'Eve'}

userMap.a = undefined      // OK, but we want error

const users: User[] = Object.values(userMap)  // error: Type 'User | undefined' is not assignable to type 'User'
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gOwIYFsIBcUcwiAlpgOYC+AULQMYD2mJUArgogLLZhHoA2gGsIIKBWKkKlALoB+IvCTVUGOrU5JeYAHTY1WPISgByAKIAbMglN0tPProBGhnPiIWAbhDv0HOvpq7JgAJhAAZhQQoVBx8QD0CVAA8gDSADRQzuzAUACSUADu2Jh5SIhMiPTMrHkOcEpcgrJqKc4AVhAMwLpe2JbsEHAAFAF8AJRxSVAVVUQAKuDQpsrIAD4cYZHRoaYScFCYTHnYcHBklDjOltDATFCgkGZrprRAA)

How can we define such an object so that:

- we can't assign it `undefined` and
- `Object.values` gives us clean value type without `undefined`?

Comment: You're looking for `--noUncheckedIndexedAccesses` and not `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`.  You don't want optional properties at all.  Changing it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKOaDW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining (after I search for duplicates). If not what am I missing?

Comment: Ah, this is looking like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/73708429/2887218

Comment: thank you @jcalz, you are right, I would accept your answer

Comment: @jcalz That's true here, but I think the issue in OP's mind is how [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) behaves differently with index signatures: https://tsplay.dev/WJXngN

Comment: Yeah, this is more or less the whole issue surrounding `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` and `--noUncheckedIndexedAccesses` and how there's really no such thing as "optional" index signatures.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964485/proper-typing-for-object-based-map?noredirect=1#comment130598000_73964485) @jcalz Right, and that's why I agree with OP that [lines 12 and 14](https://tsplay.dev/WJXngN) should produce compiler errors with that configuration setting enabled — it seems like a bug in TS.

Comment: @jsejcksn If you look at the other question I closed this as a duplicate of, my answer there mentions https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46969 which is the issue you're talking about.  It's marked as "needs investigation" and the comment from ahejlsberg there says it's effectively a design limitation.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964485/proper-typing-for-object-based-map?noredirect=1#comment130598233_73964485) @jcalz Thanks for sharing the reference!