# Typescript Partial<Record<...>> to Record<> assignment without assertion

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm struggling with creating a generic type that would serve as field selection object but with all fields optional. Also this type should be compatible without assertion with Record<string,number>

Example:

```ts
interface ITest {
    keyA: string,
    keyB: string,
    keyC: string,
}

const testObj: ITest = {keyA: "aaaaaa", keyB: "bbbbbb", keyC: "cccccc"}


//Simple functions that takes processedObj object and prints only selected keys/values
//LET'S ASSUME THIS IS API FUNCTION AND CAN'T BE CHANGED
//Key is selected only when the key is present in selectionObj and the associated value is exactly 1
//If key is not defined in selectedObj or value is different that 1, then it's skipped with log comment

function printSelectedEntriesFromObject(processedObj: Record<string, any>, selectionObj: Record<string, number>) {

    console.log("##############################")
    for (const key in processedObj) {
        if (selectionObj[key] === 1) {
            console.log(`Entry: (${key},${processedObj[key]})`)
        } else {
            console.log(`Following key was excluded or not present at all selectionObj: ${key}`)
        }
    }
}

// Let's wrap above function to make it less error prone with generic type for selectionObj
// Below is flexible selection type for generic T, all fields are optional, so we don't need to put all options, even empty object is ok 
type selectionType<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T & string, 0 | 1>>

//Some examples of selection objects follows:

//Type OK, as expected
const exampleSelectionObj1: selectionType<ITest> = {}
//Type OK, as expected
const exampleSelectionObj2: selectionType<ITest> = {keyA: 1, keyC: 0}

//Type Error (50 is not allowed, only 0|1), as expected
const exampleSelectionObj3: selectionType<ITest> = {keyA: 1, keyC: 50}
//Type Error (unknown keys are not allowed), as expected
const exampleSelectionObj3: selectionType<ITest> = {keyA: 1, NOT_EXISTING_KEY: 0}


// So far all good, but below is the problem with generic version that tries to apply selectionType<T>. 
// Type error for selectionObj:
// TS2345: Argument of type 'Partial<Record<keyof T & string, 0 | 1>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, number>'.
// Type 'Record<keyof T & string, 0 | 1>[P] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'. 
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

function versionWithGenericValidationOfSelectedKeys<T>(processedObj: Record<string, any>, selectionObj: selectionType<T>) {
        printSelectedEntriesFromObject(processedObj, selectionObj)
}
```

I would like to get this working without using assertion in generic version:
function versionWithGenericValidationOfSelectedKeys<T>(processedObj: Record<string, any>, selectionObj: selectionType<T>) {
printSelectedEntriesFromObject(processedObj, **selectionObj *as Record<string,number>***)
}

Is there any way how to improve this generic selection type?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WK3epW) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Hello, I'm a bit confused, it somehow works, but you removed the generic parameter from the "function versionWithGeneri...". When I try to reinstate it to my original form it gives me the error back. I've also found those discussion, that may suggest that this is kinda known limitation in current implementation:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73708429/why-do-object-values-for-a-partial-record-have-undefined-typings

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46969

Comment: I removed the generics intentionally. You don't need it there, no?

Comment: @wonderflame Hmm, my level of TS typing knowledge may not be super advanced. I see that there is used below type from type-samurai:
type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false;

type selectionType<T = never> = IsNever<T> extends true
  ? Record<string, 0 | 1>
  : Partial<Record<keyof T & string, 0 | 1>>;

And in the end generic funcitons is stripped from generic parameter. I don't fully understand the intention, could you maybe describe it in more detail? Is this some workaround/hack or some specific TS feature?

Comment: yeah, I temporarily used it. It is used to check whether you passed `T` or not

Comment: I presume I would like to keep the type always specified and keep the function generic. Is it possible to adjust the solution so it keeps the original form of the generic funciton, just with type update?

Comment: Does [this one](https://tsplay.dev/mxJl1w) work?

Comment: Hey! It works, thanks! :D I've noticed a strange side effect. My initial type for generic selection type (Partial<Record<keyof T & string, 0 | 1>>) allows for empty object {} as default argument in that generic wrapper function in my code. However your type does not. I'm a bit confused as creating variables with mine and your type allow creation of empty object without type error, just this difference in parameter default value. Maybe parameter defaults have a slightly different processing?

Comment: Example signature of function with that default parameter:
function versionWithGenericValidationOfSelectedKeys<T>(processedObj: Record<string, any>, selectionObj: selectionType<T> = {})

With my type it is accepted (however there is the later error I've complained and that you solved :) ), and with your type there is error, {} is not allowed

Comment: There will be no way to do it without assertion `{} as selectionType<T>` since we can't know the `T` exactly. Should I proceed with writing the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)  also makes values `undefined`:

```
type Obj = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

// type Result = {
//     a?: string | undefined;
//     b?: number | undefined;
// }
type Result = Partial<Obj>
```

We can use the built-in utility type [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to solve this, however, it should be applied to the values.

We can write a custom utility type that would map through the type using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and turn the values to non-nullable:

```
type NonNullableObj<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[K]>;
};

type selectionType<T> = NonNullableObj<
  Partial<Record<keyof T & string, 0 | 1>>
>;
```

Testing:

```
//Type OK, as expected
const exampleSelectionObj1: selectionType<ITest> = {};
//Type OK, as expected
const exampleSelectionObj2: selectionType<ITest> = { keyA: 1, keyC: 0 };

//Type Error (50 is not allowed, only 0|1), as expected
const exampleSelectionObj3: selectionType<ITest> = { keyA: 1, keyC: 50 };
//Type Error (unknown keys are not allowed), as expected
const exampleSelectionObj3: selectionType<ITest> = {
  keyA: 1,
  NOT_EXISTING_KEY: 0,
};

function versionWithGenericValidationOfSelectedKeys<T>(
  processedObj: Record<string, any>,
  selectionObj: selectionType<T>,
) {
  printSelectedEntriesFromObject(processedObj, selectionObj); // no error
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyyA1hAJ4CCAXMjlKAOYDcRpFAQrfU68WeQDC3MAxAsCAXwIEEAexA5kkHAHkARgCtaGbLgC8+dlVoByOBcumANMa7JT6p85vHhDhJ6+nkk1gRgAVxAEMGAFZAAHMTAAZQgAGwhQiAATAFFwBmwAMSg5AFsNTWSwAAo2aLkkLCw04toAJWS5KFSAHh5xWzgQcgA+azY6pNDwkAbkZvk2ztEmWxBAgvVoQYIASnw2eUU5JIA6BLlGMtMAYkur65vbu8vTDb5kGFbkMt2lAWRQKPyauqpYpbQjEYjAGDvEalcbFADaAgAush9KjkABGEFsMHIT77CBHE5lAAGmVE5FoZQAJHgBJJrDSqgD6loERREZINsSntjfMhEnVtjjiHjDsdTryccScvtjgB3JjGZByuBYfkADwQCUCqTSyDeIDkuGi2Ag4GQcFwcASCToiRhCkmNLpxKGwuQPJx0mI0mkBDA5EiKAAcgpg4EbXB1Eliu10P0UULkHCANI-EDGOSQ9CI2ihkDhyPRiBx1OI-qsPwyANBu2jMIKdCBkvxxP5wsJKMxrTtNgABTgUDC1va01aHQEWeQ6GQADI6PNusgAAzIAA+GP6-QIFZkAHo903a6oUz01RB1UGUqlZAolBe4AVIkl4vXYVp0dx7WNG832rocATQw8CrA8jxQE8zw1K9IBvT5cAfJ8X2-BsJi0AAmL831-IN-0wQDEzwYwaAxWwBHcVcqwIMDm2QdIoHyKB3gAVlXYA1UNK0bTkOU0lsBQEnIFc10xKCLxgtJb0UBD1UfZ8IFfB00M0ABmLClPAvC9CAowBBI9EyIodxWN8VgaNrejGPeYISENOUMwENVBxQTiLW43jUg2MTL1KST4I1OTkOw5S1LrDS-wAsAdNBYjaAMthg1UdAAH10gADVQWJ0FQYMAHFkpTdIAE1aGXIYqKCEJUOQAA3aAsHGAB1YAwAAC1ys1oGABAADVrWAVJLVhGBFOvFMKCwON+gqYgmWwQFJjHWYukYHo+nWYhoR-ZT1O2zT4yGLFZpiUbYLJbIsDyQpilKMo5tqFlNFsLbUOBZhkAPZBDX5BjWikAggA)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yet another step towards TS Zen state ;)